# Composer install/update failing

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm having an issue installing a package that I created....

https://packagist.org/packages/mardy-git/redirect

As far as I can tell, everything is working fine and I should be able to install it. However when I run the composer install or update I get the following error message...

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
 - The requested package mardy-git/redirect could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see  for more details.

Read  for further common problems.
```

And in my composer.json file I have:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "orno/di": "1.*",
        "orno/http": "1.*",
        "orno/mvc": "dev-master",
        "orno/loader": "1.*",
        "orno/db": "1.*",
        "filp/whoops": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/console": "2.3.*@dev",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.1.*",
        "form-manager/form-manager": "dev-master",
        "mardy-git/hmac": "0.1.*@dev",
        "mardy-git/redirect": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

This is a brand new package that I created this afternoon and I have not encountered problems like this before so I have no idea where to start looking for a solution. Everything else installs as expected if I remove the `mardy-git/redirect` row.

I have tried doing a composer self-update and that didn't make any difference.

Additional information:

`composer show mardy-git/redirect --verbose`

...resulted in the following response:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Package mardy-git/redirect not found

Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/ShowCommand.php:105
 Composer\Command\ShowCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:882
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:212
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:117
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:119
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:43
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:15
```

More Info, testing with just `"mardy-git/redirect": "dev-master"` in the composer file.

`composer install -vvv`

Resulted in the following response:

```
Downloading composer.json
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /Users/mbard/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Reading /Users/mbard/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-active.json from cache
Reading /Users/mbard/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Reading /Users/mbard/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json from cache
Reading /Users/mbard/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-stale.json from cache
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
 - The requested package mardy-git/redirect could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see  for more details.

Read  for further common problems.
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is doing this?

Comment: you look good for being 92.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Packagist is having an outage. https://twitter.com/PrincipeBorodin/status/342655643603324929

About all you can do is try to contact @packagist or the contact us page on packagist.org

I'm seeing exactly the same thing on one of my projects. If you go to https://packagist.org/packages/base-reality/php-to-javascript you can see the latest version is 0.1.17

But the doing:

```
composer show base-reality/php-to-javascript
```

gives

```
versions : dev-master, * 0.1.16, 0.1.15, 0.1.14, 0.1.13, 0.1.12, 0.1.11, 0.1.10, 0.1.9, 0.1.8, 0.1.7, 0.1.6, 0.1.5, 0.1.4, 0.1.3, 0.1.2, 0.1.1, 0.1.0, 0.0.9, 0.0.8, 0.0.7, 0.0.6, 0.0.5, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1
```

i.e. the 0.1.17 version isn't available through composer.

**Update**

It is now fixed now https://twitter.com/packagist/status/342710331547729920

Answer (score -2):

I'm having the same problem, while earlier this week I created a new package and everything went fine.

I found this old post about it: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1090, but unfortunately it doesn't give a solution.

> some package with a massive amount of replaces/suggest/requires triggered a memory issue in the package dumper (and indexer and everything else really)

EDIT: problem seems fixed now.